# React initial state. counting

Tags: reactjs

What am I doing wrong, I keep getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'count' of null. Am I not setting the initial state up properly?

```js
import React from 'react';

class User extends React.Component {
 super(props){

  this.state = {
   count: 0
  }
 }


 increment(){
  this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 })
 }

 render(){
  return(<div>
   <button 
    onClick={this.increment}>
      {this.state.count}
   </button> 


   </div>)
 }
}




export default User;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `this` to `.increment` method, because when you pass method `.increment` to `onClick` it loses context which related to `User` component. Instead of `super(props)` you have to use `constructor(props)`;

```js
class User extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 0
    }

    this.increment = this.increment.bind(this);
  }


  increment(){
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button 
          onClick={this.increment}
        >
          { this.state.count }
        </button> 
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<User />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Also you can use arrow function, like so

```
onClick={() => this.increment() }
```